# JS не работает в блоггере

Tags: javascript

Помогите проблемку решить. Вот этот код сам по себе работает исправно, но как только вставляю его в шаблон blogger - ничего не работает, и я не знаю с чем это связано. Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
<script>
    /********************************************************************************
    Copyright (C) 1999 Thomas Brattli
    This script is made by and copyrighted to Thomas Brattli at www.bratta.com
    Visit for more great scripts. 
    This may be used freely as long as this msg is intact!
    ********************************************************************************
    Browsercheck:*/
    ie=document.all?1:0
    n=document.layers?1:0

    //These are the variables you have to set:

    //How much of the layer do you wan't to be visible when it's in the out state?
    lshow=60

    //How many pixels should it move every step? 
    var move=10;

    //At what speed (in milliseconds, lower value is more speed)
    menuSpeed=40

    //Do you want it to move with the page if the user scroll the page?
    var moveOnScroll=true

    /********************************************************************************
    You should't have to change anything below this.
    ********************************************************************************/
    //Defining variables
    var tim;
    var ltop;

    //Object constructor
    function makeMenu(obj,nest){
        nest=(!nest) ? '':'document.'+nest+'.'
        this.css=(n) ? eval(nest+'document.'+obj):eval(obj+'.style')                        
        this.state=1
        this.go=0
        this.width=n?this.css.document.width:eval(obj+'.offsetWidth')
        this.left=b_getleft
        this.obj = obj + "Object";     eval(this.obj + "=this")    
    }
    //Get's the top position.
    function b_getleft(){
        var gleft=(n) ? eval(this.css.left):eval(this.css.pixelLeft);
        return gleft;
    }
    /********************************************************************************
    Deciding what way to move the menu (this is called onmouseover, onmouseout or onclick)
    ********************************************************************************/
    function moveMenu(){
        if(!oMenu.state){
            clearTimeout(tim)
            mIn()    
        }else{
            clearTimeout(tim)
            mOut()
        }
    }
    //Menu in
    function mIn(){
        if(oMenu.left()>-oMenu.width+lshow){
            oMenu.go=1
            oMenu.css.left=oMenu.left()-move
            tim=setTimeout("mIn()",menuSpeed)
        }else{
            oMenu.go=0
            oMenu.state=1
        }    
    }
    //Menu out
    function mOut(){
        if(oMenu.left()<0){
            oMenu.go=1
            oMenu.css.left=oMenu.left()+move
            tim=setTimeout("mOut()",menuSpeed)
        }else{
            oMenu.go=0
            oMenu.state=0
        }    
    }
    /********************************************************************************
    Checking if the page is scrolled, if it is move the menu after
    ********************************************************************************/
    function checkScrolled(){
        if(!oMenu.go) oMenu.css.top=eval(scrolled)+ltop
        if(n) setTimeout('checkScrolled()',30)
    }
    /********************************************************************************
    Inits the page, makes the menu object, moves it to the right place, 
    show it
    ********************************************************************************/
    function menuInit(){
        oMenu=new makeMenu('divMenu')
        scrolled=n?"window.pageYOffset":"document.body.scrollTop"
        oMenu.css.left=-oMenu.width+lshow
        ltop=(n)?oMenu.css.top:oMenu.css.pixelTop;
        oMenu.css.visibility='visible'
        if(moveOnScroll) ie?window.onscroll=checkScrolled:checkScrolled();
    }

    //Initing menu on pageload
    onload=menuInit;
    </script>

    <div id="divMenu" style="position:absolute; top:150; left:30; height:100; width:280; visibility:hidden">
        <a href="javascript://">Link1</a> -
        <a href="javascript://">Link2</a> -
        <a href="javascript://">Link3</a> - 
        <a href="javascript://">Link4</a> - 
        <a href="javascript://" onclick="moveMenu()">MENU</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Но если этот код работает исправно, то проблема в другом.
Какой толк тогда смотреть на этот JS код?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Открываем firefox, нажимаем F12, проверяем что не так.

Иногда из всех скриптов лепится один pack чтобы их ужать. Как правило, тогда скрипты лепят в одну строку => в нормальном их состоянии иногда интерпритатор может опустить ошибку "забыл поставить **';'** ", а вот когда код превращается в одну строку - интерпритатор уже не понимает перехода на сл. строку.

Например, уже вижу:

```
oMenu.css.visibility='visible'
```

Где ";" ? 
Вот еще :

```
oMenu.css.left=-oMenu.width+lshow
```

Ты принципиально не обозначаешь концы строк ?

Ставлю 100$ на то, что проблема в этом :D

Comment: Просто этот скрипт я нашёл. а сам я в этом вообще ничего не смыслю. Я не понимаю когда ; надо когда нет) Для меня это темный лес)